# I want to define a type of callback function , one parameter is boolean , another parameter's type depends on this boolean type

Tags: typescript

I am writing a callback function type.

One parameter called A is boolean , another parameter called B depends on this boolean parameter:

- if A is true , B will be an object
- if A is false , B will be undefined

like this

```js
login({callback : (success , res) => {
    if(success === true){
        console.log(res.a) //ok
    } else{
        console.log(res.a) // error: res is undefined
    }
}})
```

I wrote a type but it does not work

```js
interface Options {
    callback?: <T extends boolean>(success: T ,res: T extends true? {a : string}:never) => void;
}

login({callback : (success , res) => {
    if(success === true){
        console.log(res.a) //ok
    } else{
        console.log(res.a) // also ok
    }
}})
```

Comment: if(success === true) is a pleonasme

Comment: Why send the boolean at all?

Comment: @GuerricP, I can't see where the return value of the callback is used. So I don't see a problem there. However maybe @wlsyne could provide the function definition for the `login` function; it should look like `function login(options: Options) {/*...*/}`, correct?

Comment: Instead of defining a polymorph callback property in the `Options` interface you could modify it like that: `interface Options { onSuccess?: (res: {a:string}) => void; onError: () => void }`. Then you could use it like `login({onSuccess: (res) => console.log(res.a), onError: () => console.error('some error on login')})`

Comment: @Jupiter yep , but this is a legacy code  wrote by Javascript not typescript , and there is no onSuccess callback in the options(I agree your point ,onSuccess makes more sense),what I am doing is writing type for this legacy code

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WYBVzw) meet your needs?  There's a current limitation in TypeScript that will not allow you to write `(success, res) => ...` and have the compiler track the correlation between `success` and `res`.  (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44730 addresses some of it, but not all).  You can write `(...args) => ...` and use the `args` array, as shown.  If this works for you (given the limitation) I can write up an answer; if not, please elaborate on what I'm missing so I can see if it can be addressed.

Comment: @jcalz wow! It's a elegant solution , but when my colleagues use this function , they must use (...args) , finally I decide to add onSuccess callback and onError callback to options to handle this two conditions rather than in one callback

Comment: @wlsyne Sure, that makes sense.  Would you like me to write up an answer with the above approach that explains how it works and why you currently get any closer to your desired use case due to limitations in TS?  Or do you not want an answer?

Comment: @jcalz Now I use your approach to give limitation to success and res in the old callback function, and also add onSuccess callback and onError callback to options , I think my problem is solved , thank you very much for your suggestion 

Comment: I've written an answer, for completeness.

Comment: @jcalz Thx , that helps me a lot, I will spend some time to ingest this part of knowledge of Typescript 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the point of view of the implementation of `login()`, it would be best for the `callback` property of the function parameter to accept arguments which are *either* of type `[true, {a: string}]` *or* of type `[false, undefined?]`.  Traditionally you would write this as an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) with multiple call signatures:

```
function login({ callback }: {
  callback: {
    (success: true, res: { a: string }): void;
    (success: false, res?: undefined): void;
  }
}) {
  callback(true, { a: "hey" });
  callback(false);
}
```

You will get a little more type safety if instead you represent the function as taking a [rest parameter of a tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions), or rather, a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of tuple types:

```
function login({ callback }: {
  callback: (...args:
    [success: true, res: { a: string }] |
    [success: false, res?: undefined]
  ) => void
}) {
  callback(true, { a: "hey" });
  callback(false);
}
```

When calling `callback(true, {a: "hey"})` or `callback(false)`, either version work, but you can't really get type safety when implementing the callback itself with overloads.  For the rest of this answer I will assume you're using the union-of-tuple-rest-parameter approach.

---

The union `[success: true, res: {a: string}] | [success: false, res?: undefined]` is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), where the first element (with an index of `0`) is the *discriminant* property.  If you have a value `args`, you can check `args[0]` to determine whether or not the second element (with an index of `1`) is a `{a: string}` or `undefined`.

So when calling `login()`, you can get type safety if you use `args` as a rest parameter and check its `0` and `1` indices:

```
login({
  callback: (...args) => {
    if (args[0]) {
      console.log(args[1].a) // okay
    } else {
      console.log(args[1].a) // error: undefined
    }
  }
})
```

But you can't get the same safety with an arrow function that takes two separate parameters instead of a rest parameter:

```
login({
  callback: (success, res?) => {
    if (success) {
      console.log(res.a) // error!
    } else {
      console.log(res.a) // error
    }
  }
})
```

The compiler does not track the *correlation* between `success` and `res`.  This is a current limitation in TypeScript.  It still doesn't track the correlation if you use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
login({
  callback: (...[success, res]) => {
    if (success) {
      console.log(res.a) // error!
    } else {
      console.log(res.a) // error
    }
  }
})
```

Both of these run into the same problem where assigning the pieces of the union to `success` and `res` variables break the correlation.  TypeScript 4.4 [added a feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#control-flow-analysis-of-aliased-conditions-and-discriminants), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#44730](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44730), which helps a *little*, as it lets you use `success` to narrow `args`, but it still doesn't let you use `success` to narrow `res`:

```
login({
  callback: (...args) => {
    const [success, res] = args;
    if (success) {
      console.log(res.a) // error
      console.log(args[1].a) //ok
    }
  }
})
```

In that pull request it says:

> [T]he pattern of destructuring a discriminant property and a payload property into two local variables and expecting a coupling between the two is not supported as the control flow analyzer doesn't "see" the connection. ... We may be able to support that pattern later, but likely not in this PR.

So there's some hope that in a future version of TypeScript you can write `(success, res?) => ...` and things will magically work.  For now, though, you have to refactor your code a bit.

---

And this, of course, leaves aside a more simple refactoring: just forget `success` entirely and use `res` instead:

```
function fixLogin(cb: (res?: { a: string } | undefined) => void) {
  login({ callback: (success, res?) => cb(res) });
}

fixLogin((res?) => {
  if (res) {
    console.log(res.a) // okay
  } 
})
```

After all, `success` doesn't give you any additional information over `res`.  If `res` is present and defined, then `success` had to be `true`, and if `res` is `undefined`, then `success` had to be `false`.  For all I know your code is a toy example and a similar refactoring isn't possible, but I would be remiss in not pointing this out, since it considerably simplifies both the call to and implementation of `login()`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-X451-RcAMNIDjURMCfhPKBEDXS0ek3V0Bm0Clim4CD61mbCT1wl9RAnEUmSbHDn1HfkCKktDKP+BUOGVaB4CQfwAA8ABkFwgagOj6Lx2G0XR9DAQxWTdUiJXI6Ugh3cNzBcloaNIOjoWmDczOrYyx1mdM8w0mADIXYKPGYwS0T6GDhDE+TgqkxA0PIPJZyMIA)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not possible. When you type a function with generic types, you type the parameters and the return values. The generic types are resolved/inferred in the code where the function is being called and it verifies the consistency of the parameters and return value types.

Inside the implementation, the types do not resolve so they remain `T` and `T extends true? {a : string } : never`.

The best thing you could do is use type checks **outside** `callback`'s implementation, and use function overloading instead of conditional type, in order to make the second parameter optional:

```
function login({ callback }: { callback: Callback }) {
    const success = !Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    if (success) {
        callback(success, { a: 'test' }); // OK
        callback(success); // Fails
    }
    else {
        callback(success, { a: 'test' }); // Fails
        callback(success); // OK
    }
}

interface Callback {
    (success: true, res: { a: string }): void;
    (success: false): void;
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAGzgcxmAFAb0RAQ2WQCMCIBrRAXwC5E9DizL6BhI08q6gSgYCwAKESj8CAM5REEkBAgBTCRMQBeRAEIAsgSgALAHTBUcAE5Yd+g6YJgAJnAC2WfgCpEAJl4BuYWMQwwIhYsvJKEvw4fv5iTFyUIXKKygA0DIgE9ADkUEpQWTQ+iAD0xYgA8gDS0TH4nCwUiWHKRaWIAGIEMMgSNTR9Cj0KgiK1dczcTckSaXiZiDl5BXzeJWWd3b2jtXENU+GtZVV91MKnQsKYuabA5MMcE5Qj-vvK9FCmIApppkr0c-QpKZMGhCvQAG5wGB2XzbYKhab0W5DXgQqEws5AA)